# cómo consumir un servicio web de WCF en xamarin.android

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android

El servidor no pudo procesar la solicitud debido a un error interno. Para obtener más información sobre el error, active IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (ya sea desde ServiceBehaviorAttribute o desde el comportamiento de configuración) en el servidor para enviar de nuevo la información de excepción al cliente o active el rastreo según la documentación de Microsoft .NET Framework SDK. inspeccionar los registros de seguimiento del servidor.

aquí está el método del servicio web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui llamo al metodo del webservice
[image: this is where I call it]

agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Vas a tener que ser mas claro con el error. Lo que describiste como error es el generico que dice que algo no anduvo, pero obviamente eso no reporta el error real. vas a tener que hacer lo que te dice el error para encender el trace de errores y que puedas saber que pasa realmente. Asi como esta, no se te puede ayudar de ninguna forma.